# Get minimum date of one group from dataframe A using .groupby() and replace the date in dataframe B where conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, date, data-manipulation

I have two dataframes as shown below:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1/1/2016', '1/2/2016', '1/3/2016', '1/4/2016', '1/5/2016', '1/6/2016', '1/7/2016', '1/8/2016', '1/9/2016', '1/10/2016', '1/11/2016', '1/12/2016', '1/13/2016', '1/14/2016', '1/15/2016', '1/16/2016', '1/17/2016', '1/18/2016', '1/19/2016', '1/20/2016', '1/21/2016', '1/22/2016', '1/23/2016', '1/24/2016', '1/25/2016', '1/26/2016', '1/27/2016', '1/28/2016', '1/29/2016', '1/30/2016', '1/31/2016', '2/1/2016', '2/2/2016', '2/3/2016', '2/4/2016', '2/5/2016', '2/6/2016', '2/7/2016'],
                     '445_Week': [20160101, 20160101, 20160101, 20160101, 20160101, 20160101, 20160101, 20160101, 20160102, 20160102, 20160102, 20160102, 20160102, 20160102, 20160102, 20160103, 20160103, 20160103, 20160103, 20160103, 20160103, 20160103, 20160103, 20160104, 20160104, 20160104, 20160104, 20160104, 20160104, 20160104, 20160104, 20160201, 20160201, 20160201, 20160201, 20160201, 20160201, 20160201],
                     'Week': ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','4','4','4','4','4','4','4','4','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1',],
                     'Sales': ['10', '15', '20', '15','10','20', '10','15', '10', '15','20', '15','10','20', '10','15','10', '15', '20', '15','10','20', '10','15', '10', '15','20', '15','10','20', '10','15', '10','15', '20', '15','10','20']})

df_B = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1/1/2016','1/2/2016', '1/3/2016', '1/4/2016','2/1/2016'],
                     '445_Week': [20160101, 20160102, 20160103, 20160104, 20160201],
                     'Week': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
                     'Sales': ['10','15', '20', '15', '10']})
```

I am working with a 4-4-5 calendar as shown in the '445_Week' columns above. My goal is to replace the 'Date' column in df_B which is in 'm/w/yyyy' format with the correct 'Date' as shown in df_A. I want to achieve this by getting the minimum date for each group in '445_Week' from df_A. This is the ideal end result:

```
df_C = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1/1/2016','1/9/2016', '1/16/2016', '1/24/2016','2/1/2016'],
                     '445_Week': [20160101, 20160102, 20160103, 20160104, 20160201],
                     'Week': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
                     'Sales': ['114.375','14.285', '14.375', '14.375', '15']})
```

Notice here that the Sales portion of the final dataframe is simply the average of the values by each group.

Here's what I have attempted so far:

```
dfc = df_A.groupby('445_Week')['Date']
new_df = df_A.assign(Date = dfc.transform(min))
```

This just creates a new dataframe from df_A in which we get the minimum Date per 445_Week. I believe the next step would be to merge these two dataframes, but I'm unsure if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to simply replace the data in the desired column and add another additional one with the calculation.
I will convert the column new_df['Sales'] type to float, column df_A['Date'] to date format.
If you do not convert the df_A['Date'] column, then the row with index 1 will not be calculated correctly (it will be 1 1/10/2016). Your first average is 114.375, it should be 14.375000.

```
df_A['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A['Date'])
dfc = df_A.groupby('445_Week')['Date']
new_df = df_A.assign(Date=dfc.transform(min))
new_df['Sales'] = new_df['Sales'].astype(float)

aaa = new_df.groupby('Date')['Sales'].mean()
df_B['Date'] = aaa.index
df_B['Sales'] = aaa.values

print(df_B)
```

Output

```
        Date  445_Week Week      Sales
0 2016-01-01  20160101    1  14.375000
1 2016-01-09  20160102    2  14.285714
2 2016-01-16  20160103    3  14.375000
3 2016-01-24  20160104    4  14.375000
4 2016-02-01  20160201    5  15.000000
```

If the column df_B['Date'] data is needed in its original format, then you can convert it back to string:

```
df_B['Date'] = df_B['Date'].dt.strftime("%-m/%-d/%Y")
```

Output

```
        Date  445_Week Week      Sales
0   1/1/2016  20160101    1  14.375000
1   1/9/2016  20160102    2  14.285714
2  1/16/2016  20160103    3  14.375000
3  1/24/2016  20160104    4  14.375000
4   2/1/2016  20160201    5  15.000000
```